# How to check the pointwise convergence of series function in general?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check the pointwise convergence of series function in general?Is there an other way except finding the sum?

Answer (score 0):

You mention pointwise convergence of a series of functions, which ensures that the series converges for every argument, i.e. you show for every $x$ in your domain that the real/complex series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
converges. You have all convergence criteria for real/complex series at hand. But this does usually not give you any information about properties of the limit.

It depends on the kind of convergence result you are interested in. If you are interested in finding out whether the limit function lies in a certain function space, or satisfies certain regularity conditions, you should check for convergence with respect to an appropriate (function) norm.

Other options include local uniform convergence, uniform convergence. Generally speaking, there are many ways a series can converge, for every topology on a function space, you can characterize convergence of function series therein.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the sum in general is unpractical, so it is not the standard way. There is however a number of theorems offering criteria regarding convergence. Have you got any particular example in mind?

Comment: by showing the normal convergence

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ One option is to use Cauchy Criterion:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N$: 
$\forall m, n >N$:

$|f_{m}(x)+f_{m+1}(x) +...+f_n(x)| < \varepsilon$

$(2)$ Another option is Weierstrass M-Test:

If each $f_n$ is bounded, so $|f_n| \le M_n$, then:

If $\sum^{\infty}_0M_n$ converges, then $\sum^{\infty}_0f_n$ converges as well.

Note: both of these criterions are also sufficient to prove uniform convergence.